# Have to use -o Acquire::ForceIPv4=true to do apt-get update/upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, ipv6, ipv4

I am looking for an other workaround to my problem that apt-get upgrade/update/install wont work via IPv6. I cant use the software center neither can I use the system update center for anything. I only get updates etc. by forcing IPv4.

Is there any way to make a permanent change in the system so I don't have to type the whole line in every time I want to update/upgrade/install something.

If there is a solution to the update and software center problem. Which, I guess, is caused by the same problem I am having with the update/upgrade line.

I really don't know what this problem is caused by. A general Solution would be awesome just as well :D

Comment: Well it's a clean installation. I am relatively new to Ubuntu and don't really have a clue what the problem might be caused from.

Comment: Do you know the reason that IPv6 isn't working for you? The answer given below helps you to force IPv4, but solving the IPv6 problem would probably be a better long term solution :)

Comment: I really don't have an idea. I didn't block it inside the router configurations or anything. It just doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
exec sudo -i
nano /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99force-ipv4
```

In the open file paste this line:

```
Acquire::ForceIPv4 'true';
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> Save file

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> Close nano

This should force to use IPv4 in place of IPv6.

Comment: Thank you for your answer/input. I tried what you told me to try. It didn't work. Same as before. :/